# React Redux - Conditional selector

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

In my application i have many part of the state that is significative only when the user is logged in.

When the user is logged in and navigate directly to a page, router display the page but have to make async call, so a piece of the state is not yet populated.

Now, suppose i have to show a button on navigation bar that have to take a part of the state, but this state is not populated since the async call finis.

More pratically, i have this selector:

```
export const getSelectedCustomer = state => state.systems.selectedCustomer;
```

With this, there are no problem, because `selectedCustomer` is part of the `initialState` reducer

The problem is in this selector:

```
export const getSelectedCustomerName = state => {
    return state.systems.entities[getSelectedCustomer(state)].customer;
}
```

The part of the state `entities` in `initialState` is an empty array and will be populated on async call.

So, when the application start and i map (with connect - `mapStateToProps`) the selector `getSelectedCustomerName` i get the error because `entities` is empty and sure, `customer` field do not exist yet

A simple solution if to take in place some `if-else`, but i will have to do this in "every" part of the application.

I'm asking if there is a better solution to avoid this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const NullCustomerEntities = {
    customer: "Anonymous"
}

export const getSelectedCustomer = state => state.systems.selectedCustomer;

export const getCustomerEntities = state => {
    return state.systems.entities[getSelectedCustomer(state)] || NullCustomerEntities;
}

export const getSelectedCustomerName = state => {
    return getCustomerEntities(state).customer;
}
```

This is a classic example of a [Null Object pattern](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tell-dont-ask#example-4)
 (hope you don't mind the code being in Ruby).

Comment: Stumbled on this.  Enjoyed the JavaScript/Ruby juxtaposition.